# What is the true meaning of CCC-310?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism, good-and-evil, omnipotence, summa-theologica

I've been reading the Catechism, and reached the [310th point](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P19.HTM#:%7E:text=310%20But%20why,reached%20perfection.175); it's about Divine Providence and the scandal of evil. I am having a hard time understanding the following passage:

"With infinite power God could always create something better ([174](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P19.HTM#:%7E:text=174%20Cf.%20St.%20Thomas%20Aquinas%2C%20STh%20I%2C%2025%2C%206.)). But with infinite wisdom and goodness God freely willed to create a world 'in a state of journeying' towards its ultimate perfection."

It sounds contradictory to me. It states that God has both infinite power and infinite goodness. It seems, then, that it would only be possible for Him to create "something better", since not creating "something better" while being able to do so would be in disagreement with His infinitely good nature. How does the Catechism avoid this apparent contradiction? It links to the Suma Theologica, but I am not proficient enough in Philosophy to understand it.

If possible, I would like an answer that solves this problem *within* the Catechism, i.e. without usage or substitution by other arguments.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting question, and I hope you will enjoy your time here.

Comment: Infinite power within the limits of infinite goodness. Infinite goodness within the limits of infinite justice and so on...No contradiction...It's kind of like infinite rail track going only in one direction.